# Are these sizes correct for an array of variables and an array of pointers to variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size

Are the sizes and statements for the entire array stated in the comments in the code below correct?

```
//gArray uses sizeof(char)*100 = 1*100 = 100 bytes.
char gArray[100];

//gArray uses sizeof(char)*100*50 = 1*100*50 = 5000 bytes.
char gArray[100][50];

//gArray is a 2D array, each element is a pointer to a char (although
//char data type is irrelevant).
//gArray uses sizeof(void*)*100*50 = (4 or 8) * 100 * 50 = 20000 or 40000 bytes.
char* gArray[100][50];
```

Thanks.

Comment: C++ is type safe. So best to use the correct types when arguing. Though in this case void* is the same size as char*. You should write `sizeof(void*)*100*50` as `sizeof(char*)*100*50`

Comment: PS. Don't assume that pointers are 4/8 bytes. This may be common now on PC but have you tried on your cellphone or that medical scanner that was installed in the 80's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just print out the values:

```
char gArray1[100];

char gArray2[100][50];

char* gArray3[100][50];

std::cout << "gArray1  " << sizeof(gArray1) << "\n"
          << "gArray2  " << sizeof(gArray2) << "\n"
          << "gArray3  " << sizeof(gArray3) << "\n";
```

I get:

```
gArray1  100
gArray2  5000
gArray3  40000
```

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(char)` is by definition `1` so it would be 100, 5000, and 20000 or 40000 (on most systems - 128+ bit pointers aren't prohibited by the standard).

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(char)` is defined to always be equal to 1 by the c++ standard, if I remember correctly.
So, no, those are incorrect.